# Can I find an index from the minimum of one array and then use that same index to call a column from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to find the index of the minimum value of a 1D array and then find the corresponding column from a 2D array, I do this using:

```
find_index = np.where(min(function())
```

where the function creates the array in question. The array is a single column with 8 values. This seems to be working, but the problem arises when I then try to find the corresponding column of the 8x8 array. I've tried

```
find_column = varr[:,find_index]
```

and also

```
column_needed = [:,find_index]
find_column = np.take(varr, column_needed)
```

where varr is the 8x8 array and find_index is the index I found from the 1D array.
Is there a way to do this? I think I understand why my approaches aren't working but I can't seem to find an approach that does work.

```
varr = np.array([1],[2],[3]) 
varr2 = np.array([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]) 
find_index = np.where(min(varr)) 
find_column = varr2[:,find_index]'
```

Edited to attempt to get the code to show up as code and add a simple example, this is my first post :)

Comment: A minimal example would be helpful to clarify your question

Comment: simplify your code down to only performing this task ... make it copy and paste able so we can execute it to help

Comment: @mozway essentially each value in the column array corresponds to a column in the 8x8 array, the 0 element in the first array representing the 0th column in the second array.

Comment: A well crafted example is worth a thousand words ;)

Comment: @ScottStensland
'varr = np.array([1],[2],[3])
varr2 = np.arrayy([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
find_index = np.where(min(varr))
find_column = varr[:,find_index]'

This is a toy model of what I'm trying to do, the original code has about 15 nested functions so I couldn't simplify it. So if the minimum value (1) is index 0 in the first array, I want to pull the corresponding column from the second array, [:,0]. Thank you, I hope this helps :)

Comment: @mozway I've given a really simplified example in my above comment, although I'm not sure how to edit comments to show code

Comment: You can't really show code in comments, best is to edit the question

Comment: @kingfizzles got it, thanks for the update, I provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

It was almost correct, the issue being that `where` returns a tuple.

You can use:

```
idx = varr.argmin(axis=0)

col = varr[:, idx]
print(col)
```

Fix of your code:

```
find_index = np.where(varr.min()) 
find_column = varr2[:,find_index[0]]
```

output:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
varr = np.array([1,2,3]) 
varr2 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) 
find_index = np.where(min(varr))[0]
find_column = varr2[:,find_index]
```